# Typescript: create various child classes from static method of parent class

Tags: typescript, inheritance, circular-dependency, typing

I am fairly new to typescript and have ran into a problem concerning circular dependencies and child class instantiation from parent classes. I have a parent class that will ideally contain a static method which fetches various data and instantiates a certain child class depending on the retrieved data. I will have many child classes, thus I'd like to keep the children in separate files (thus the circular dependency problem). Here is some code for an example:

**parent.ts**

```
abstract class Parent {
  _data1: string;
  _data2: number;

  constructor (
    data1: string,
    data2: number,
  ){
    this._data1 = data1;
    this._data2 = data2;
  };

  static async createChildren(dataQueryURL: string): Promise<Array<Parent>> {
    const dataQuery: Array<Array<any>> = await getQueryData(dataQueryURL);
    // Suppose response looks like: [["foo", 3, 1], ["bar", 2, 2, "Hello world!"], ["baz", 5, 1]]
    
    const children: Array<Parent> = new Array<Parent>();
    dataQuery.forEach(data => {
      if(data[2] === 1){
        let child = new Child1(
          data[0],
          data[1],
          data[2],
        );
        children.push(child);
      } else if (data[2] === 2){
        let child = new Child2(
          data[0],
          data[1],
          data[2],
          data[3],
        );
        children.push(child);
      };
    });
    return children;
  };

  abstract doSomething(): number;
};
```

**child1.ts**

```
class Child1 extends Parent {
  _data3: number;

  constructor(
    data1: string,
    data2: number,
    data3: number,
  ){
    super(data1, data2);
    this._data3 = data3;
  };

  doSomething(): number {
    return this._data2 * this._data3;
  };
};
```

**child2.ts**

```
class Child2 extends Parent {
  _data3: number;
  _data4: string;

  constructor(
    data1: string,
    data2: number,
    data3: number,
    data4: string,
  ){
    super(data1, data2);
    this._data3 = data3;
    this._data4 = data4
  };

  doSomething(): number {
    return this._data2 / this._data3;
  };
};
```

As you can clearly see, there must be circular dependencies between parent.ts <--> child1.ts and parent.ts <--> child2.ts. Typescript throws an error at compilation time due to this.

Furthermore, when I call the static method createChild, I return an array of classes that all inherit from parent but I don't know for sure which child classes will be in the array. As a result I promise an array of parents. I have a hunch this is an incorrect way of thinking about this problem. Reason being: if I want to go through my array of children and get _data3, typescript will not expect _data3 to be contained within the classes as the parent does not contain _data3.

I can solve the circular dependencies by getting rid of the static method and creating another ts file with a function for createChildren. I can solve the _data3 typing problem by promising an array of any. However both of these seem like messy solutions.  I am hoping for some insight on how to deal with both the circular dependencies and promises in a more elegant fashion. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break the compile-time import dependency by making a [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import) (and remove the top-level import from `parent.ts` module)

Something like :

```
  static async createChildren(dataQueryURL: string): Promise<Array<Parent>> {
    const dataQuery: Array<Array<any>> = await getQueryData(dataQueryURL);
    // Suppose response looks like: [["foo", 3, 1], ["bar", 2, 2, "Hello world!"], ["baz", 5, 1]]
    
    const children = await Promise.all(dataQuery.map(async data => {
      if(data[2] === 1){
        return new (await import('./child1')).Child1(
          data[0],
          data[1],
          data[2],
        );
      } else if (data[2] === 2){
        return new (await import('./child2')).Child2(
          data[0],
          data[1],
          data[2],
          data[3],
        );
      } else {
        throw new Error(`Unsupported type: ${data[2]}`);
      };
    }));
    return children;
  }
```

Regarding your second question, I'm not sure to fully understand it :

- Why not bring `_data3` to `Parent` class if this field exists (with same type) in both `Child1` and `Child2` ? or make an abstract getter for this field at the Parent level ?
  In that case, you would be able to retrieve it in a generic fashion.
- In your example, it seems like you can have responses mixing both `Child1` and `Child2` shaped data structures : it seems legit to me to then have a generic `Array<Parent>` result type.
  We *may* consider having a more specialized type if you would tell me that responses will always contain the same type of Child.

Regards,

Comment: The dynamic imports are a good idea, thank you! In terms of the _data3, the abstract example of my code is not the best. Truly, _data3 will have variable typing depending on the data received from the query which is why I decided to only implement them in the children. It will be consistent within each child class though. Sorry, I should have clarified this.